# 'Google is not defined' when I add directionsDisplay and Service

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My map was working perfectly displaying a fixed marker, and a marker of the user's shared location. However now when I add directionsDisplay and directionsService variables along with some other code, the map doesn't load at all and I get a console error of 'google is not defined'.

Below I will post my working code, and I'll annotate all the the new lines which I added so you can tell which ones.

If I comment out the lines (as below) the map works fine and displays the console error directionsDisplay not defined, which I would expect obviously but when I add these lines in google hates me.

## Also I've currently tried:

- removing async defer from the api key
- testing in Chrome and FF, with incognito mode and private browsing

## EDIT

Thanks to @Jaromanda X, who noticed google wont be recognized until the initMap function is called so I moved the variable into calcRoute function as it didn't need to be global anyway.

I will update the code, please note that this unfortunatley doesn't make the route calculate correctly, still working on that :/

HTML:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my key is here&callback=initMap"></script>
```

JS:

```
var directionsDisplay;

var map;


var markers = [];


var initMap = function() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chesters = new google.maps.LatLng(52.19147365, -2.21880075);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: chesters
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: chesters,
    title: 'Chesters Restaurant',
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map
  });


  markers.push(marker);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

}


var showPosition = function(position) {
  var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: userLatLng,
    title: 'Your Location',
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });


  markers.push(marker);


  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }


  map.fitBounds(bounds);

    calcRoute(userLatLng);
}

function calcRoute(userLatLng) {
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(userLatLng.lat, userLatLng.long),
        end = new google.maps.LatLng(52.19147365, -2.21880075);

    /*bounds.extend(start);
    bounds.extend(end);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);*/

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }

    });
}

function errorHandler(error) {
  console.log('Geolocation error : code ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorHandler, {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  maximumAge: 60000,
  timeout: 27000
});
```

Comment: `google` will be undefined until `initMap` callback is called ... so, yeah

Comment: @JaromandaX I see, that makes sense thank you. Any idea on how I could better layout the code por should I just add the service variable into the calc route function

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the google maps directions api? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

I would have posted as a comment but apparently cant do that before 50rep.